# How do I kill libre writer from the cmd prompt? I tried killing swriter.exe but libre writer is still there

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

How do I kill libre writer from the cmd prompt?  I tried killing swriter.exe but libre writer is still there

I've noticed that libre writer has a tendency to crash when I have quite a bit open on my computer.

But having crashed it doesn't really close easily.

I looked at the shortcut for libre writer and it's `"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\swriter.exe"`   No idea and can only guess what the "s" is meant to stand for

But when I try `taskkill /f /im swriter.exe` it successfully closes swriter but libre writer is still open

On the computer i'm I wouldn't mind dragging the crosshair icon of process explorer onto a libre writer window to see what process it's associated with,  but since the libre writer window is crashed, I can't restore it so it's just a maximised crashed window and I can't check it.

I can't restart the computer right now as there's stuff open and not yet saved in notepad (notepad is reliable software and won't be crashing but I am not ready to restart yet 'cos of the unsaved notepad windows)

I'm wondering what process I can kill off that would kill off libre writer?

Comment: *No idea and can only guess what the "s" is meant to stand for* - It should be assumed that "s" stands for "star" - that is, **soffice** is [**StarOffice**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarOffice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking LibreOffice Writer from Task Manager leads to `soffice.bin`.
Try to kill it.

**Powershell**

```ps
Get-Process -Name soffice.bin | Stop-Process -Force
```

**Command line**

```
taskkill /f /im soffice.bin
```

Comment: FYI, there is a "typo" it is -Name not -Mame

Comment: @esponapule Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If in task manager you go to the applications tab, then it lists any document opened in libre writer and if you right click that then click "go to process", it says soffice.bin

Also, process explorer aside from the crosshair option, another option is "find handle" that people usually use to find what process is locking/using a file. But it works for this too, if you look for one of the opened files then it catches what's locking it, as soffice.bin

And indeed, taskkill /f /im soffice.bin does the job.